# React / Redux remove 'active' from non-related component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx

I am using React-Photon kit to create a front-end, and while terrific it does present some unknowns for me.

Specifically, I have a sidebar navigation `<Photon.NavGroup>` that dynamically paints a top nav-bar on change. This goes through Redux / Thunk and works well, relying on an `index` value. When an `onClick` to the `NavGroupItem` happens, a dispatch updates the store and everything rerenders as desired.

I've added a persistent `Home` button to the top nav that has no relation to the sidebar. It dispatches an `index:0` from `onClick` and this causes a load of the desired Home page and resets the top nav by updating the store.

What I'm having difficulty understanding is the appropriate way to update (remove) the currently selected NavGroupItem's `class = 'active'`.

I've looked at a number of articles but they all involve existing relationships of Parent / Child. In this case that doesn't exist (cousins?)

I'd likely approach this outside of React as ...

```
const els: any = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
  if (els != null) {
    [...els].forEach(el => {
      el.getAttribute('class').replace('active', '');
    });
  }
```

but I'd like to stay within the framework.

My sidebar looks like:

```
// @flow
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
import * as Photon from '../vendor/photon';

/** Thunk actions */
import updateSidebar from '../actions/sidebar-actions';

/** Action Type Constant */
import { UPDATE_SIDEBAR_INDEX } from '../constants/ActionTypes';

class Sidebar extends Component {
  onSelect: Function
  state: {
    index: number
  }

  action: {
    type: string,
    index: number
  }

  constructor(props: Object) {
    super(props);
    this.onSelect = this.onSelect.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      index: 0
    };
  }

  onSelect(index: number) {
    this.setState(() => ({
      index
    }));

    const setNav = () => {
      switch (index) {
        case 1:
          return '/Dashboard';
        case 2:
          return '/Logistics';
        case 3:
          return '/Operations';
        case 4:
          return '/Reporting';
        case 5:
          return '/Transactions';
        default:
          return null;
      }
    };

    this.action = {
      type: UPDATE_SIDEBAR_INDEX,
      index
    };
    this.props.updateSidebar(UPDATE_SIDEBAR_INDEX, this.state, this.action);
    this.props.navigateTo(setNav());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Photon.Pane ptSize="sm" sidebar>
        <Photon.NavGroup onSelect={this.onSelect.bind(this)} >
          <Photon.NavGroupItem eventKey={1} glyph="gauge" text="Dashboard" />
          <Photon.NavGroupItem eventKey={2} glyph="globe" text="Logistics" />
          <Photon.NavGroupItem eventKey={3} glyph="cog" text="Operations" />
          <Photon.NavGroupItem eventKey={4} glyph="print" text="Reporting" />
          <Photon.NavGroupItem eventKey={5} glyph="publish" text="Transactions" />
        </Photon.NavGroup>
      </Photon.Pane >
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: *) => ({
  updateSidebar: (type, state, action) => dispatch(updateSidebar(type, state, action)),
  navigateTo: (path: string) => dispatch(push(path))
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Sidebar);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
[...els].forEach(el => {
  el.classList.remove('active');
});
```

note: this doesn't work on IE<10, you could use jquery and use `$(el).removeClass('active')`

Comment: the `getattr().replace()` is getting the class string, replacing it but not setting it again

Comment: Thanks - i did feel close ~